# How to change a DIV padding without affecting the width/height ?

Tags: css, html

I have a div that I want to specify a FIXED width and height for, and also a padding which can be changed without decreasing the original DIV width/height or increasing it, is there a CSS trick for that, or an alternative using padding?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Solution is to wrap your **padded div**, with **fixed width outer div**

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">

        <!-- your content -->

    </div><!-- end .inner -->
</div><!-- end .outer -->
```

**CSS**

```
.outer, .inner {
    display: block;
}

.outer {
    /* specify fixed width */
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0;
}

.inner {
    /* specify padding, can be changed while remaining fixed width of .outer */
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Just wan't to clearify, I'm not sure, but this would only work for horizontal padding right? As height: auto doesn't fill up the parent like width: auto does.

Answer (score 241):

Declare this in your CSS and you should be good:

```
* { 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
     box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

This solution can be implemented without using additional wrappers.

This will force the browser to calculate the width according to the "outer"-width of the div, it means the padding will be subtracted from the width.

Comment: it works like a charm i am newbie just search this property and it works Great Man .....

Comment: Are there any side effects that I should be mindful when using that?

Comment: This solution is better than the accepted one, and it is safe to not use prefixes anymore: http://shouldiprefix.com/#box-sizing

Comment: @adswebwork You saved my large amount of my time. Thank you.

Comment: How about height? This does not seem to resolve the height growing with padding-top|bottom.

Comment: Is this more proper than the accepted solution? And what is the cons using these?\

Answer (score 20):

Sounds like you're looking to simulate the IE6 box model. You could use the CSS 3 property [box-sizing: border-box](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-model) to achieve this. This is supported by IE8, but for Firefox you would need to use `-moz-box-sizing` and for Safari/Chrome, use `-webkit-box-sizing`.

IE6 already computes the height wrong, so you're good in that browser, but I'm not sure about IE7, I think it will compute the height the same in quirks mode.

Comment: css3 is still very new like the iPad :)

Answer (score 10):

try this trick

```
div{
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
 box-sizing: border-box;      
}
```

this will force the browser to calculate the width acording to the "outer"-width of the div, it means the padding will be substracted from the width.

Comment: this is the same as @adswebwork's answer, right? I appreciate the explanation of how it works, but that's probably better as a comment

Comment: why post an identical answer

Answer (score 5):

To achieve a consistent result cross browser, you would usually add another `div` inside the `div` and give that no explicit width, and a `margin`. The `margin` will simulate `padding` for the outer div.

Answer (score 4):

if border box doesnt work you can try adding a negative margin with your padding to the side that's getting expanded. So if your container is getting pushed to the right you could do this.

```
.classname{
  padding: 8px;
  margin-right: -8px;
}
```

Comment: the best answer and most elegant way to achieve this imho!