# padding increases width and height of div

Tags: html, css

how can I modify these divs so that when I change their padding, their height and width do not expand? I have tried to implement

```
.outer, .inner {
    display: block;
}

.outer {
    /* specify fixed width */
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0;
}

.inner {
    /* specify padding, can be changed while remaining fixed width of .outer */
    padding: 5px;
}
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2225620/1252748)

by giving the parent divs `fixed_width` and `relative_container` `width:700px;height:100px; padding:0px;`, but when I apply padding to `.content` or `.obscure`, the divs expand to cover `.extra_margins below`. Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/loren_hibbard/ZmJ9R/

Comment: `box-sizing:border-box;`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use CSS3 `box-sizing` property to do this:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Supported in IE8+ but some browsers may require a prefix:

http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing

Comment: yeah, i would like to use it without css3 if possible. just for support reasons... Doesn't the link I used indicate that it is possible without css3 somehow? Thanks!

Comment: excellent answer, apparently i've been doing this wrong for a long time. and that compatibility chart is perfectly reasonable.\

Comment: yeah, true. that compatibility chart is not terrible at all. Thanks!

Comment: box-sizing is implemented in every modern browser as low as IE8 (doesn't work in IE7). It may be referred to as CSS3 - but it's actually really well supported. Just make sure you add the prefixes